# Iframe. How to load links into an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe loading in my page. Ex.: http://thissite.com.

```
<iframe width="400" height="300" frameborder="0 scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.mysite.com/page.php">
```

Actually if I click on a link into the iframe I get the new page into the iframe itself.

I want the new page loading from http://thissite.com. and not into the iframe.

How to tdo that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `target="_top"` on `<a>` link.

Comment: you mean <a> instead of src?

Comment: ok I got you ;) that's worked

Answer (score 0):

If you control the site showing in the iframe you can just add this attribute inside the code for the link:

```
target="_top"
```

which will open the link in the full body of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Set the '`target`' attribute to '`_top`' to load it in the main window.